# How can I get the html of a page as a string in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to get the html of the current page that is loaded as a string, so that I may manipulate it and use that information later on. I am needing to use this in a Firefox extension, and I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work.

I originally tried storing the value using .outerHTML, which I had seen and got to work in other places. Here is an example of how that worked:

```
var pageHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

I also tried searching just for the piece that I needed at the time, like so:

```
document.getElementById("header")
```

However, neither of these seem to access the HTML. I assume this is because the code is operating in the browser, not in the document itself. How can I go about accessing the HTML 'document' of a page loaded in a tab from a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox addon SDK includes a module called [`page-mod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) which is intended for this purpose. Content scripts run under `page-mod` will be run in the context of the web page, rather than the typical sandboxed context.

From that page's documentation:

> You can modify the document in your script:
>
> ```
> var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
>
> pageMod.PageMod({ include: "*.mozilla.org",
>                   contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML =' +
>                                  '"<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";' 
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Can I store values in extension variables from within the pagemod?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that - unfortunately my own experiments with the SDK haven't gotten far beyond using page-mod just for DOM manipulation. The documentation is fairly good at laying out the limitations, and how to communicate with your main addon code.

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure either haha. I am wondering if this method would work to store values from the script on the page into variables that operate in the extension. Basically, is there a way to output a variable from this pagemod and save it in a variable that can be manipulated by the extension itself? I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what I'm looking for, but it's the only idea I've got at the moment ;D

Comment: @JasePellerin Yup, read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port)